# Deadlock when using EF6 with MySQL to clone entity

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, deadlock

I wrote a method, which has to help me with cloning entities in DB as seen below.

```
public static DBTable AddNewClone(long id, long id_foreign_key)
    {            
        using (DatabaseModel db = new DatabaseModel())
        {
            var newObject = (DBTable)db.Entry(db.DBTable.Single(x => x.id == id)).GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
            newObject.id_foreign_key = id_foreign_key;
            newObject.used = 1;

            string q = $"UPDATE ..."; //updating some values in same table, not touching id_entity
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(q);

            db.DBTable.Add(newObject);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return newObject;
        }
    }
```

I have an exception in this method sometimes, which is caused by the deadlock on row

```
var newObject = (DBTable)db.Entry(db.DBTable.Single(x => x.id == id)).GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
```

which doesn't  make sense to me. If I get it right, I am just reading value which is already in DB (this is almost untouchable entity in our scenario). When I was using this cloning process on multiple places in code, it was running well, there is this weird exception since I made this method for doing this job.

Could someone see what is wrong with this code, why I am getting those deadlocks? (If I executed this for e.g. 1000-2000times, I've got 2 deadlocks.)

Comment: If the database reads are executed as locking reads (select ... from update), then the select will lock the records that are scanned. If you have multiple clients running this code, then they may lock records with select that the other wants to update. Use innodb status monitor to find out what exactly is happening there. A deadlock out of 1-2000 transactions does not sound that bad, you may decide to handle the deadlock by reissuing the same sql statement again.

Comment: @Shadow Hi there and thanks for your answer. Yes, it is not bad and I already did it, but, still, it looks not good.

That UPDATE statement is just Update something from select from select from select. And exception is not executed on this line. So, could be really that?

Comment: Look at innodb status monitor and you will know for sure.